# How would I stop one tab from closing as the other opens in my script?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, tabs

So I have 3 scripts

Script 1 which opens tab one and closes upon mouseleave()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var myTimeOut;
var rightSlide1 = ".rightslide1";

$(rightSlide1).mouseenter(function(){
    myTimeOut = setTimeout(function (){
        $(rightSlide1).stop(true,true).animate({"left": "9.5vw"}, "300");
    }, 1000);
});


$(rightSlide1).mouseleave(function(){
    clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
    $(rightSlide1).animate({"left": "37vw"}, "300");
});
```

Script 2  which opens tab one and 2 and closes upon mouseleave()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myTimeOut;
    var rightSlide1 = ".rightslide1";
    var rightSlide2 = ".rightslide2";

    $(rightSlide2).mouseenter(function(){
        myTimeOut = setTimeout(function (){
            $(rightSlide1).stop(true,true).animate({"left": "9.5vw"}, "300");
            $(rightSlide2).animate({"left": "14vw"}, "300");
        }, 1000);
    });


    $(rightSlide2).mouseleave(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
        $(rightSlide1).animate({"left": "37vw"}, "300");
        $(rightSlide2).animate({"left": "41.5vw"}, "300");
    });
});
```

And Script 3  which opens tab one, two and three and closes them all upon mouseleave()

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var myTimeOut;
    var rightSlide1 = ".rightslide1";
    var rightSlide2 = ".rightslide2";
    var rightSlide3 = ".rightslide3";

    $(rightSlide3).mouseenter(function(){
        myTimeOut = setTimeout(function (){
            $(rightSlide1).stop(true,true).animate({"left": "9.5vw"}, "300");
            $(rightSlide2).animate({"left": "14vw"}, "270");
            $(rightSlide3).animate({"left": "18.5vw"}, "300");
        }, 1000;
    });


    $(rightSlide3).mouseleave(function(){
        clearTimeout(myTimeOut);
        $(rightSlide1).animate({"left": "37vw"}, "300");
        $(rightSlide2).animate({"left": "41.5vw"}, "270");
        $(rightSlide3).animate({"left": "46vw"}, "300");
    });
});
```

So basically on this page, I have 3 tabs. 1|2|3| and I want to to be able to open the tabs and have them slide against each other.  I have gotten the tabs to slide left as I want but the problem is now I cant figure out how to keep tab 1 open while someone opens tab 2. It closes when I go to open tab 2 which just looks tacky.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are two tiny issues, which are causing your problem:

**Issue #1:**  Your tabs close right away, when you leave, but the opening is delayed by 1 second. If you want to keep it like that, your tabs will always close first and open delayed. If you lessen the delay time, they may close and open simultaneously. However, they will keep sliding round a bit too much. I would recommend to get rid of that delay, or add it to the close animation as well. You also could make one general delay, when entering the accordion.

**Issue #2:** This is the more important one. You are using jQuery's stop() method. First, you should use it consistently throughout all your animations, so they get executed immediately and not queued, which can result in very weird behaviour. Second, don't set the second parameter to *true*. This will make the current animation to go to its end immediately, which causes the tabs to "jump". If you set it to *false* instead, the tab will stop at its current position and continue with the new animation from this point on. This will result in a far better user experience.

If you get rid of the delay, and change the second parameter, your close will beautifully slide against each other.

With best regards,
Syntac

Comment: I will give this a shot tomorrow evening. Thank you so much

Comment: Thank you very much for the help

Comment: @Weber No problem :). Im glad it helped!